# Extract data from a text file using a RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex, data-extraction

I am trying to write a RegEx to extract data from a file.

The file looks like the following:

```
"a123 100 Start"
"a123 101 Today"
"a123 101 Tomorrow"
"a123 102 End"
```

The file contains multiple lines of records just like the one above. In each line of the file there is a code on a fixed position (100 - start of record, 101 - record detail, 102 - end of record). I would like to extract from that file a structure like a `List<List<string>>` where the outer list will store all the groups of records that are in the file.

My first approach was to parse this file with a `foreach` but I think there should be a way to achieve this with a RegEx. And being that I would like to expand my RegEx knowledge, I think that is a great example for me.

Is it possible for such data to be parsed with a RegEx? If so, can someone help out with the RegEx itself?

Thanks!

Comment: How you group and which data you need to store in inner string list?

Comment: @Damith, the grouping will be on the code (100) and the data in the inner list will be the lines between the 100 and 102 lines. So, all the lines in the example above.

Comment: without REGEX   `List<List<string>> result = File.ReadAllLines("textfile.txt").Select(line => line.Split().ToList()).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file has this specific structure, you do not need to use `Regex`. Just use `Split(" ")` and the result array for each line.

`Regex` has performance penalties.

But if you like to use `Regex` anyway, you can use `Regex.Match(line, "[\S]+ [\S]+ [\S]+")` for this file structure.